# Translating Obj-C pass by reference to Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to translate a simple method from Obj-C to Swift, and I can't work out from the docs how to do it.

I've simplified the method to a bare bones example that illustrates what I don't understand:

```
- (void)getChar:(unichar *) outChar
{
    *outChar = 'a';
}
```

The nearest I've got to this so far in Swift is this:

```
func getChar(inout outChar:CMutablePointer<unichar>) -> () 
{
    outChar = ("a" as NSString).characterAtIndex(0)
}
```

But of course I get the error for the 3rd line: Unichar is not convertible to CMutablePointer.

The BuildingCocoaApps pdf has short sections about using pointers from Obj-C, but I can't work out how it relates to this.

Can someone explain how to do this?

EDIT:
I am calling the method/func from Obj-C like this:

```
unichar c;
[myObject getChar:&c];
```

I've realised that I need to add @objc before the func, because I'm calling it from Obj-C. And that now gives me more errors.

Comment: There's certainly pass by reference in Obj-C. In the language, because Obj-C contains all of C functionality. And in the Cocoa API. Look for example at the NSScanner API, where all the scan* methods use pass by reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I see you are trying to use the Swift class methods from Obj-C.

**Make sure your Obj-C implementation file (.m) has the Swift import**:
`#import <##Your-Project-Name##>-Swift.h`
This file is not visible in your project but the import is required to use Swift classes in Obj-C (see [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_75)).

I created an Obj-C command line program with this in my `main.m`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ObjCTest-Swift.h"  // <- VERY IMPORTANT!

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        unichar someChar = '\0';

        // This is my Swift class
        TextGenerator *textGenerator = [[TextGenerator alloc] init];
        [textGenerator generateChar:&someChar];

        NSLog(@"Character vaue is now %d", someChar);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the accompanying `TextGenerator.swift` file:

```
import Foundation

@objc class TextGenerator : NSObject
{
    @objc func generateChar(outChar:CMutablePointer<unichar>)
    {
        let testString : NSString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
        let firstChar = testString.characterAtIndex(0)

        // Access the unichar * in an unsafe context to set the value directly
        outChar.withUnsafePointer{ charPtr in charPtr.memory = firstChar }

        // Alternatively, this is the shorthand form ($0 is the first arg)
        outChar.withUnsafePointer{ $0.memory = firstChar }
    }
}
```

The real takeaway here is you **cannot** mutate the value stored by a `CMutablePointer<Type>` directly. You must use `withUnsafePointer` to access the value in an unsafe manner within a separate closure. This is probably intentional to avoid programmer error with pointer mishaps.

Comment: But I am interoperating from Obj-C. I'm calling it from there. See edit.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect your requirements.